# Ubuntu Slow in Virtualbox even with 256mb vram

Tags: virtualbox

So I'm trying this virtualbox software which I heard was relatively good.

Though I'm not pleased with the performance that I'm getting. I'm running the 13.xx version of Ubuntu. I have the FX-8320. I have switched my vram to 256mb which is maximum and performance has improved. I'm still thinking that its' not as fast as I would like. I'm thinking it might be the CPU which has not been giving enough power but I'm not sure.

I have installed the virtualbox drivers and it didn't really help.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you have assigned the virtual machine 256MB of "virtual" RAM, or 256MB of *video* RAM?

- What do you consider to be poor performance?
- What are you trying to do, specifically?
- What kind of workload are you trying?  I mean, if you're trying to do smooth 3D architectural walk-throughs or play high frame-rate games, maybe you're just barking up the wrong tree completely here, and you should just be doing that on an operating system installed on bare metal using your video card manufacturer's optimized video drivers, and so on.

Having said that; make sure:

- that virtualization support is enabled in your BIOS configuration.
- make sure that the virtual machine configuration in VirtualBox has hardware virtualization assist enabled.
- In your storage settings, disable use of the host's disk cache, because if you have that enabled, you have both your VM and your host machine caching disk writes, which is redundant at best and 'can' affect performance and also potentially lead to data loss and/or tears.
- Try switching your virtual hard drive controller to SCSI or SAS, if you're using SATA.

I have to assume, that your Ubuntu VM is running a graphical user interface, right? How much virtual RAM does the machine have to work with?

Try enabling 2D video acceleration.  What kind of video hardware do you have?  Is there even any point in assigning the virtual machine 256MB of video RAM (if that's what you're doing), based on the actual underlying hardware that you have?  Virtual machines can perform pretty handily, but they can't magically make your underlying hardware more capable than it is.